# Создание скошенного угла для div, у которого есть border

Tags: css, html, border

Результат, который надо получить, на картинке:
[image: Необходимый результат]

Структура:

```
<div class="promo-text">
                <h2>Нет слова "Нет"</h2>
                <p>Данное слово неуместно в нашей работе . Любая задача, уровень сложности и оперативность — мы умеем удивлять! Альтернативу никто не отменял и мы всегда ее находим.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: В чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Если применять clip-path, срезается рамка. Не получается сделать так, чтобы осталась скошенной именно рамка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решился добавлением родительского блока.

```css
.outer {
  padding: 3px 3px 6px 3px !important;
  background-color: @dark-color !important;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner {
  z-index: 100;
}

.promo-text {
  background: gray;
  padding: 40px 60px 120px 55px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 55%, 0% 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 55%, 0% 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-text outer">
  <div class="promo-text inner">
    <h2>Нет слова "Нет"</h2>
    <p>Данное слово неуместно в нашей работе . Любая задача, уровень сложности и оперативность — мы умеем удивлять! Альтернативу никто не отменял и мы всегда ее находим.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Можно сделать скрипт, который будет лепить примерно такую конструкцию:

```css
.promo-text{
  width:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: #777777
}
.promo-text::after{
    content: " ";
    width: 210px;
    height: 49px;
    margin-top: -36px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    transform: rotate(-11deg);
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-text">
                <h2>Нет слова "Нет"</h2>
                <p>Данное слово неуместно в нашей работе . Любая задача, уровень сложности и оперативность — мы умеем удивлять! Альтернативу никто не отменял и мы всегда ее находим.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А если фон будет другого цвета или разноцветный? не годится...

Comment: Но как в таком случае сделать адаптивность? Используется bootstrap, и блок меняет свою ширину

Comment: @Алёна с помощью js

Comment: или фоновый рисунок